# python: setting values of indices in every slice of 3d numpy array with corresponding 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, 3d, project

I have a 3d stack of size 8x512x512 and would like to set values for each of the 8x --512x512-- arrays based on two single corresponding 2d 512x512 arrays.

Array1 is a binary with some shape I want and Array2 has the values I want projected through the 3d array. I would like values from Array2 to appear on each 512x512 slice in the 3d array where Array1 values are equal to 1. So if Array1 is a bounding box and Array2 is a cat picture whose face lies within the regions of the bounding box...I want the cat face projected onto each of the 8x slices of the 8x512x512 array.

I think this is an easy problem but can only think of what I assume is the dumb way to do this:

```
Array1 = np.zeros((512,512)); Array1[10:20,40:60]=1
Array2 = np.load(somecatpicture)
Array3d = np.random.rand(8,512,512)

for imnum in range(Array3d.shape[0]):
    tmp = np.copy(Array3d[imnum,...])
    tmp[Array1==1] = Array2[Array1==1]
    Array3d[imnum,...] = tmp
```

or:

```
Array1 = np.zeros((512,512)); Array1[10:20,40:60]=1
Array2 = np.load(somecatpicture)
Array3d = np.random.rand(8,512,512)

stack1 = np.array([Array1 for i in range(Array3d.shape[0])])
stack2 = np.array([Array2 for i in range(Array3d.shape[0])])
Array3d[stack1==1] = stack2[stack1==1]
```

I assume there's some way to do this without a loop or list comprehension:

```
Array3d[:,[Array1==1]]=Array2[Array1==1]
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this with a smaller example that we can visualize

The image and mask.  `mask==1` is the same as converting it to boolean:

```
In [280]: img = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)*10                                                  
In [281]: mask = np.zeros((3,4),int); mask[1,1:3]=1                                            
In [282]: mask = mask.astype(bool)                                                             
In [283]: mask                                                                                 
Out[283]: 
array([[False, False, False, False],
       [False,  True,  True, False],
       [False, False, False, False]])
```

So the selected part of the image is:

```
In [284]: img[mask]                                                                            
Out[284]: array([50, 60])
```

Define the 3d target array:

```
In [285]: arr = np.arange(24).reshape(2,3,4)                                                   
In [286]: arr                                                                                  
Out[286]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 17, 18, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

apply the mask - with a `[[0],[1]]` indexing of the first dimension:

```
In [287]: arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None],mask]                                            
Out[287]: 
array([[ 5,  6],
       [17, 18]])
```

and do the insert:

```
In [288]: arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None],mask]=img[mask]                                  
In [289]: arr                                                                                  
Out[289]: 
array([[[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
        [ 4, 50, 60,  7],
        [ 8,  9, 10, 11]],

       [[12, 13, 14, 15],
        [16, 50, 60, 19],
        [20, 21, 22, 23]]])
```

`np.arange(arr.shape[0])[:,None]` is the key to applying the insert to all blocks.